# How to use recurrence relation to obtain generating function

Tags: combinatorics

I have a recurrence 
(n+1)f(n+1,m,r)=(1+2m)f(n,m,r)+(n+2r)f(n-1,m,r).
I am trying to find the generating function for this but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: You would need some starting points, for example, the value of $f(0,m,r)$ and $f(1,m,r)$ (since your recurrence uses $n$ and $n−1$ to compute the $n+1$-th step). Otherwise the recursion goes backwards forever. 

And what does this recurrence have to do with combinatorics?

Comment: f(0,m,r)=1 and f(1,m,r)=1+2m. a generalized special combinatorial number satisfies this recurrence.

Comment: Have you tried to compute $f(n,m,r)$ for the 4 or 5 first values of $n$ in order to find a pattern?